# Storyboard - auto return to previous screen on condition

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.2, uistoryboard

I am using Storyboard and trying to return back to a previous screen when a certain condition is met.  IE, the username is not found on login.

Essentially, the user types in their info and presses a button.  If the info is incorrect or not found, I show a UIAlertView message to inform them of the incorrect info.  Due to the order things are done, the screen transition happens on the button press before I have checked any data with the server.  So I can't halt the screen change before I check.

I am checking for the user's button press in the UIAlertView for signal to go back with this method ..

```
 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

I am trying to use the one line in that method to return to the previous screen but nothing happens.  I assume storyboards work differently but I don't know the syntax to return to the previous screen with them.

Thanks.

Comment: This does not really answer your question here but it might be better to pop back to the login screen and present a non-modal message that lets the user know what is going on. UIAlertView should be used very sparingly and non-modal is ofter better User Experience.

Comment: This is fine.  But how do I pop back to the first screen at all automatically?  The issue here isn't me trying to do it in UIAlertView.  I can't get back to the first screen automatically at all unless the user presses a 'back' button on the next screen.

Answer (score 1):

If your storyboard pushes a view controller then you can always programatically pop it. this is not a problem. The problem here is that the UIAlertView is shown using an animation and therefore you can't perform another animation in one go.

1. So you have two options. Popping the view controller without animation should work but then the user might not realize where he is getting to.
2. You can put the call that pops the viewcontroller into a helper method and call this methd like this: `[self performSelector:@selector(myPopHelperMethod:) withObject:nil  afterDelay:0.8f]`. This should pop your view controller after 0.8 seconds which is enough to let the UIAlertView finish its animation.

Comment: I set the popViewControllerAnimated: to NO and it didn't seem to effect anything.  I also tried the helper method.. I am still calling [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
in myPopHelperMethod right?  If so, it doesn't do anything either.  Is it possible to halt the view change when the user presses the button until I say to?  I don't know how to programmitically set when screens are changed with storyboards.  I only know how to simply connect them VIA the ctrl+click drag in the storyboard view.

Comment: Are you sure that self.navigationController is not nil, when you attemp to pop your view controller?

Comment: In further investigation it appears storyboarding doesn't use navigationcontrollers at all by default.. They must be added in, which is obviously why it would be null.  But that would make me think one isn't necessary at all to do what I want in the first place.

Comment: @JesseDurham I think this is not completely correct. Every View Controller has the `navigationController` property but that does not mean that it has to be set. Generally if you want a `UINavigationController` you have to create it and add a `rootViewController` to it. In the storyboard you can click on the desired `UIViewController` in your story board and choose the following from the menu: `Editor > Embed in > Navigation Controller`

Comment: that's correct.  I tinkered around with that a bit, adding in a Navigation Controller and setting the root view as my initial login screen.  It didn't seem to effect anything, I still cannot go back to the first screen automatically using that syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess your `self.navigationController` is nil, which makes your method a no-op.

Comment: In further investigation it appears storyboarding doesn't use navigationcontrollers at all by default.. They must be added in, which is obviously why it would be null.  But that would make me think one isn't necessary at all to do what I want in the first place.